# Restriction makes the whole map an open mapping?

Tags: general-topology

$X, Y$ are two topologcial spaces, and $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a continuous map.

$U$ is a dense open subset of $X$, and the restriction of $f$, $U\rightarrow Y$ is a open map.

Then the whole mapping $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is an open map, too?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following counterexample could work.

Let $X=\{x,y,z\}$ with the topology $T=\{\emptyset, \{x\}, \{x,y\}, X\}$ and consider $Y=\{s,t,r\}$  with the topology $S=\{\emptyset, \{s\}, Y\}$.

Consider now the function that sends $x$ to $s$,  $y$ to $r$ and $z$ to $t$.

This is continuous and open if restricted to the open dense subset  $\{x\} \subset X$, but it is not globally open.